# Inner join between integer and string

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do inner join on two table from two different database.

```
SELECT 
    trans.user_id
FROM
    (SELECT 
        user_id, timestamp AS transection
    FROM
        `Abcd_Transactions`.`Transaction_Archives`) AS trans
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        userid
    FROM
        Abcd_QNA.qa_posts
    WHERE
        type = 'Q') AS ques ON trans.user_id = ques.userid
```

But in above trans.user_id is STRING but ques.userid is INTEGER. so it gives me unexpected result. In order to convert ques.userid into char. i have used.

```
convert(ques.userid, char)
```

But, it takes infinite time.

I have found many link to such problem and claims to have solution but i have not got an appropriate answer.

Comment: Provide table definitions and some sample data set

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, yes query will take because will not use index due to use of find_in_set function because different datatype-

```
SELECT 
    trans.user_id
FROM
    (SELECT 
        user_id, TIMESTAMP AS transection
    FROM
        `Abcd_Transactions`.`Transaction_Archives`) AS trans
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        userid
    FROM
        Abcd_QNA.qa_posts
    WHERE
        TYPE = 'Q') AS ques ON FIND_IN_SET(ques.userid,trans.user_id)
```

Even below query can be fast-

```
SELECT trans.user_id, trans.TIMESTAMP AS transection, ques.
FROM `Abcd_Transactions`.`Transaction_Archives` AS trans 
JOIN Abcd_QNA.qa_posts AS ques ON FIND_IN_SET(ques.userid,trans.user_id) 
WHERE ques.type='Q';
```

Comment: yes as your schema is not correct, so it will take time if you will execute on a big data set. you can check if you can reduce data by any other filter based on indexed field.